# Form to post into database table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a form that posts the index.php input to my database table using index.php and connection.php. Also I'm trying to specify everything else to be in letter format except the phone number (puhelinnumero) in numeric format using bind_param, but it gives me this error:

[image]

Here is the index.php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="lomake-container">
            <form action="connection.php" method="POST">
                <h2>Ilmoittautumis lomake</h2>

                <div class="lomake-block">
                    <label for ="nimi">Etunimi</label>
                    <input type="text" name="etunimi" id="nimi" placeholder="Etunimi">
                </div>

                <div class="lomake-block">
                    <label for ="sukunimi">Sukunimi</label>
                    <input type="text" name="sukunimi" placeholder="Sukunimi">
                </div>

                <div class="lomake-block">
                    <label for="male">Mies</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="male" name="sukupuoli">
                </div>

                <div class="lomake-block">
                    <label for="female">Nainen</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="female" name="sukupuoli">
                </div>

                <div class="lomake-block">
                    <label for="other">Muu</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="other" name="sukupuoli">
                </div>

                <div class="lomake-block">
                    <label for ="sähköposti">Sähköposti</label>
                    <input type="text" name="sähköposti" id="sähköposti" placeholder="Sähköposti">
                </div>

                <div class="lomake-block">
                    <label for ="salasana">Salasana</label>
                    <input type="text" name="salasana" id="salasana" placeholder="Salasana">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for ="puhelinnumero">Puhelin numero</label>
                    <input type="text" name="puhelinnumero" id="puhelinnumero" placeholder="Puhelin num.">
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Lähetä">

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Here is the connection.php

```
<?php

$etunimi = $_POST["etunimi"];
$sukunimi = $_POST["sukunimi"];
$sukupuoli = $_POST['sukupuoli'];
$sähköposti = $_POST['sähköposti'];
$salasana = $_POST['salasana'];
$puhelinnumero = $_POST['puhelinnumero'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = '';
$database = 'palvelu';


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else {
    echo "Yhteys onnistui";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into lomake($etunimi, $sukunimi, $sukupuoli, $sähköposti, $salasana, $puhelinnumero)
    values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
}
$stmt->bind_param("sssssi",$etunimi, $sukunimi, $sukupuoli, $sähköposti, $salasana);
echo "onnistui jea";
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();




?>
```

Here is the table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't parameterise column names, but anyway I'm pretty sure that's not actually your intention, and you've possibly slightly misunderstood how to build an `INSERT` query. You need to specify the column names you want to insert into. The variable values you're currently trying to use in place of column names will be automatically assimilated into the query via the `?` placeholders when MySQL receives the query.

Also you forgot to put the last value into the `bind_param` command.

Lastly your logic is a tiny bit flawed - if the connection fails, then your code will die. There's no need for the `else`. If it doesn't die, just carry on.

Try this instead:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Yhteys onnistui";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into lomake(`nimi`, `sukunimi`, `gender`, `email`, `password`, `number`) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssi",$etunimi, $sukunimi, $sukupuoli, $sähköposti, $salasana, $puhelinnumero);
echo "onnistui jea";
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

P.S.

Here is the MySQL documentation reference for `INSERT`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html